# water leakage alarm consumption in stand by mode?

Tags: pcb

[image]
[image]

Hello.
This is a pcb of water leakage alarm,which works with 9v battery and
activates the piezo speaker when the three metal legs(on the bottom of the plastic)came in contact with water.The unit is working.
I had been told that the consumption of this unit in stand-by(the battery is connected,but the speaker is not activated)is about 0.1 mA.
I measured the current consumption with digital ammeter in order to check
it(even in micro amper scale),but there wasn't any readind,as it is open circuit.So,my question is:
According to my description and the attached pcb photos,Is this pcb consumption,in stand-by,zero or it actually consume some current?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to add a schematic.

Comment: That 0.1 mA is really a worst-case current, in practice it will be and must be a lot smaller. Like 10x smaller or more. I have seen designs of 40 years ago based on CMOS logic chips which lasted "forever" on a 9 V battery. Actually it is limited by the battery's lifetime, not the current consumption of the circuit. Assuming the alarm rarely sounds ! If you cannot measure the current I suspect your meter is not sensitive enough. You could place a 1 kohm resistor in series with the 9V battery and measure the voltage drop across it. Then use ohm's low to determine the actual current.

Comment: Indeed we need a schematic and the type number of that 8-pin chip (my guess is that it is an opamp).

Comment: Bimperlrekkie@my ammeter can measure 1 micro amper,doesn't it enough?I am sorry,i made a deep search in the web,but i couldn't find any schematic for that alarm.The 8-pin chip doesn't have any identified sign on it.

Comment: What component is actually consume this small current?only the micro controller?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie,I have placed 1kΩ resistor in series with the 9v battery,as you suggested,but there wasn't any voltage drop reading across it.The dmm can measure min:100µV.If the reading was showing 100µV,it could indicate that the current is 100nanoA(100µV/1KΩ=100nanoA),but,as i mentioned,there was no voltage drop reading.This test might prove that the current is even less than 0.1µA,but could this addition 1KΩ resistor in series with the battery,cause the current to be lower(<0.1.Aµ)than the actual current,while without the resistor the current maybe higher(~1 µA)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "stand-by,zero". But, if I had designed such a thing, the 8-pin chip would be a µC which is running for about 100µs, checks the sensor during this time, and if no alarm had to be on, puts itself into deep sleep mode for about 10s.

It should be obvious you could only measure the deep-sleep current, which is likely to be less than 1µA, in that case.

---

EDIT: Schematic showing the currents and voltages due to a 99MΩ parasitic resistance against ambient.

This is to show how complicated it is to measure small currents.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL9S0w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you happen to know Ri and Rp **exactly**, you are okay. You can safely drop the additional 50mV (or whatever it is) and get the voltage drop over the resistor Rm and thus, the current into U1.

BUT, **DO YOU?**

Comment: Couldn't it be that the µC in the photo is shut-off completely?I read that they are such µC.What do you think?

Comment: No, there aren't. Those who claim are in deep sleep. This means they consume less than 1µA while they wait for an interrupt. For example one from their watchdog timer. 1µA is less than the self-discharge current of most batteries.

Comment: I have placed 1kΩ resistor in series with the 9v battery,but there wasn't any voltage drop reading across it.The dmm can measure min:100µV.If the reading was showing 100µV,it could indicate that the current is 100nanoA(100µV/1KΩ=100nanoA),but,as i mentioned,there was no voltage drop reading.This test might prove that the current is even less than 0.1µA,but could this addition 1KΩ resistor in series with the battery,cause the current to be lower(<0.1.Aµ)than the actual current,while without the resistor the current maybe higher(~1 µA)?

Comment: May you answer my question,@janka?

Comment: You cannot measure such low currents with a simple DMM because its leakage current is no longer neglible.

Comment: Do you mean,@Janka,that the current consumption is only due to the leakage of the transistor?

Comment: I've added a schematic and explanation.